# create trigger syntax issue migrating mysql from 5.6 to 8

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER `set_avatar_null` BEFORE UPDATE ON `mybb_users`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
   if new.uid = -1 then
     Insert Into Log (uid, Page, Params, Time) values (new.uid, 'set_avatar_null',new.avatar,      NOW());
   set new.avatar = '', new.avatardimensions='';
  end if;
end
```

this syntax works fine in mysql 5.6, but in 8.0 throws this exception:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: It does produce the same error in [this fiddle with MySQL v8.0.12](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ineTgmZDBAxZ8p5gRL4zkt/0) but no error in [this fiddle with MySQL v8.0.26](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9c7b1798e547e3696ac20008afa9f57). A bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DELIMITER` command to change the delimiter before the statement. See the [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ineTgmZDBAxZ8p5gRL4zkt/2).